# Trying to connect to Azure Cosmos DB from GoLang Application

Tags: azure, go, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I've created a Cosmos DB and I am trying to connect to it through my GoLang application. Here is the code:

```
type DB struct {
    MongoDB *mongo.Client
}

var dbConn = &DB{}

func NewMongoDB(connectionString string) (*mongo.Client, error) {
    //Create a context to use with the connection
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(connectionString).SetDirect(true)
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to initialize new Cosmos DB client %v", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to initialize connection %v", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    err = TestConnection(client, &ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return client, err
}

func ConnectNoSQL(connectionString string) (*DB, error) {
    //Create a new Mongo DB client
    db, err := NewMongoDB(connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    dbConn.MongoDB = db

    return dbConn, err
}

func TestConnection(client *mongo.Client, ctx *context.Context) error {
    if err := client.Ping(*ctx, nil); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not PING database due to - ", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

...

// 2. Connect to database
    log.Println("Connecting to database ..") //Create the URI we will use to connect to out cosmosDB
    connecturi := fmt.Sprintf(
        "mongodb://%s:%s@%s.documents.azure.com:%s/%s?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&appName=@%s@",
        *dbUser,
        *dbPassword,
        *dbHost,
        *dbPort,
        *dbName,
        *dbHost)
    db, err := driver.ConnectNoSQL(connecturi)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot to databse ...")
    }
```

Here is the error message:

> 2022/02/01 22:48:53 server selection error: context deadline exceeded,
> current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr:
> scenario-prototype-db.documents.azure.com:443, Type: Unknown, Last
> error: connection() error occured during connection handshake:
> connection({COSMOS-DB-NAME}.documents.azure.com:443[-22]) length
> of read message too large: length of read message too large }, ] }

I am not sure what is going on. I followed tutorial from Microsoft's official documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/create-mongodb-go, but did not manage to do it.

It looks like it:

1. Creates a new client via mongo.NewClient
2. Manages to connects to it
3. FAILS at TestConnection when I try to PING it.

Any thoughts? Also, could this be due to the fact that my API is set to SQL api and not Mongo API (probably silly question, but I would like to understand meaning of error)

Thanks!

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question: you cannot use MongoDB drivers against a Cosmos DB instance that uses the SQL API. You have to create a MongoDB API instance, which works just fine with all MongoDB drivers.

Comment: Agree to what @DavidMakogon mentioned, ran into this problem in the past.
CosmosDb is an umbrela name for multiple DB endpoints, but you need to provision them individually and they are not interchangeable, ( you cannot switch from sql to mongo)

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem turned out to be exactly as specified in the question and in the comments as well. Resource was created as an SQL API instead of MongoDB, even though error is a bit misleading or at least not detailed enough.